# Arrary.equal(charAt) cannot be found

Tags: java, arrays, compiler-errors

I am coding a program that searches for a specific character and displays it's position as soon as it is found in a string, which is input by the user. I've tried changing the syntax around on line where the error is popping up, but the same error continues to occur. I am very new to coding so I would really appreciate the help!!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Lab10
{
   public static String character;
   public static String input;
   public static int position;
   public static StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder(input);


      public static void main(String[] args)
      {         
         Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

         System.out.print("Enter a string: ");
         input = keyboard.nextLine();

         System.out.print("Enter a character: ");
         character = keyboard.nextLine();

         System.out.println(" ");

         getPosition();

         System.out.print("The position of the first '" +   character +"' found is" + position);        
       }

     public static int getPosition()
     {
        for (position = 0; position <= str.length(); position++)
        {  
            char charAt = str.charAt(position);

            if (character.equals(charAt))
            {
               return position;
            }
            else
            {
               position++;
            }      
         }
         return position;
     }

}
```

Thank you everyone for pointing out my syntax error. It compiled just fine after I fixed the error, BUT, a whole other error came up when I tried compiling it in the terminal/cmd

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError Caused     by: java.lang.NullPointerException  at java.lang.S
```

Comment: It is `equals` and not `equal`.

Comment: A `String` will never equal a `char`. Exactly what is the code intended to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its equals() my friend :D ,i've been throw many similar issues xD.

## would recommend using intellij ide to avoid syntax errors.

Comment: I've never heard of intelliji. What exactly is it?

Comment: its an awesome ide for jave development .fast , responsive and shipped with the best suggestions for bug fixes and variable naming,

you can get it from the official website for free at https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/

Comment: thank you so much for the suggestion! Would you know how i could fix the most recent error that i added to my question? This is the second time an error has popped up in my terminal and not when compiling :(

Comment: actually one advantage of using IDE is error report that shows you the line on which you have the error , just look at the debugging log ,or even more , try adding breakpoints to your code blocks and trace the execution flow line by line to know exactly how your code is complied and where the error might be

Comment: I'm trying to see where there could be some more discrepancies, but I'm not sure what an error relating to NullPointerException would be. I've hear of this error.

Comment: Null pointer exception is a common error when dealing with arrays/ variables,it's when the application attempts to use an object reference that has the null value . In Your code you are calling getposition() without passing value to it , str.charAt will return null because str is never define.  Add the parameter str to the function so it will be public static int getPosition(String str,Char character), also when you call it from the main function add the input as parameter getPosition(input, character) .

Comment: I really can't thank you enough. There is one last little bit i gotta fix, but your help has saved me at least an hour of blankly staring at the screen lol.

Comment: Happy to help:), let me know if you manage to run the program successfully 

Comment: I was able to run it and i actually used that ide you told me about. I really like it!! But i have a logical error in my getPosition module where its outputting position of 0 every time. I'm just going to have my professor look at it tomorrow, because i have two other programs to finish :/. Btw you're really handsome, in case you didn't know lol.

Comment: thanks !! i really appreciate that  , in case you haven't figured it out this is a the final working code based on your initial code .  https://repl.it/repls/FussyHarmlessCertifications

Comment: Anytime lol. I was able to get it eventually. Just another simple mistake I didn't notice. Thanks, again for the help !!!

Answer (score 1):

This should be `character.equals(charAt))` not `character.equal(charAt))`and you need to compare `String` with a `String` not `Char` with a `String`.

Answer (score 0):

For comparing two characters it is better to use == because equals method is
used for strings and objects.

```
 if (character == charAt){
     return position;
 }
```